# создавать localstorage для каждого нового объекта массива

Tags: reactjs, typescript

**Ресторан выбор столика и заказы. И под картинкой заказа есть таймер , в чём сообственно трабл когда заказов много на кухню летит мой localstorage ломается потому что работает только по одному заказу я обновил страницу если заказ 1 всё гуд время стопится на том месте котором остановилось но если заказов больше путаеться время и не останавливается не могу понять как обратиться ко всем заказам сразу**

```
    useEffect(() => {
    setState(JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('count')));
}, [])

React.useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('count', JSON.stringify(state));
    let interval;
    if (timeMinus) {
        interval = setInterval(() => {
                if (state.timeMinus) {
                    setState({
                        timeMinus: state.timeMinus - 1,
                        minuts: Math.floor((state.timeMinus - 1) / 60),
                        seconds: state.timeMinus - Math.floor((state.timeMinus - 1) / 60) * 60 - 1,
                    });
                }
                else if (state.timeMinus === 0) {
                    const state2 = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('timePlus'));
                    setState2({
                        timePlus: state2.timePlus + 1,
                        minuts2: Math.floor((state2.timePlus + 1) / 60),
                        seconds2: state2.timePlus - Math.floor((state2.timePlus + 1) / 60) * 60 + 1,
                    });
                }
            /* } */
        }, 1000)
    } else if (!timeMinus) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, [state.timeMinus, state2.timePlus,])
```

**Тут будет код кухни и всех заказов**

```
<Box style={{position: 'absolute', right: 10, bottom: 75,}}>
                                        {order.dishesDone[dishIdx]
                                            ? <MyTimer timeMinus={false} timePlus={false} />    
                                            : <MyTimer timeMinus={dish.time} timePlus />}
                                        </Box>
```

**Обращаюсь к каждому ордерку добавляю dish это время готовки на кухне нужно каждый заказ как я думаю добавлять в localstorage чтоб при обновление страницы мой таймер тормозился и продолжал с того момента как его остановили(обновили страницу)**

Стайт

```
const [state, setState] = React.useState<State>({
    timeMinus,
    seconds: timeMinus - Math.floor((timeMinus - 1) / 60) * 60 - 1,
    minuts: Math.floor((timeMinus - 1) / 60),
});
    const [state2, setState2] = React.useState<State2>({
        timePlus,
        seconds2: timePlus - Math.floor((timePlus + 1) / 60),
        minuts2: Math.floor((timePlus + 1) / 60),
    });
```

Comment: Покажите структуру `state`. И этот `state` это для одного заказа? Если так, то может вынести хранение данных на компонент выше?

Comment: order.dishesDone[dishIdx] сохраняться данные в отдельном компоненте и тут я создаю таймер для каждого созданного заказа

Comment: interface State {
    timeMinus: any;
    seconds: number;
    minuts: number;
}
interface State2 {
    timePlus: any;
    seconds2: number;
    minuts2: number;
}
const [state, setState] = React.useState<State>({
        timeMinus,
        seconds: timeMinus - Math.floor((timeMinus - 1) / 60) * 60 - 1,
        minuts: Math.floor((timeMinus - 1) / 60),
    });
        const [state2, setState2] = React.useState<State2>({
            timePlus,
            seconds2: timePlus - Math.floor((timePlus + 1) / 60),
            minuts2: Math.floor((timePlus + 1) / 60),
        });

Comment: Может вам подойдет [indexDB](https://learn.javascript.ru/indexeddb) для таких целей? Либо для множества заказов придется: а - плодить количество данных в localstorage по ключам вида `count[OrderNumber]`, либо сбрасывать постоянно весь стейт в хранилище, а потом в каждом компоненте заказа его перебирать и фильтровать.